# why retainAll() returning an empty list?

Tags: java, set

I have two sets A and B. I have to find the union, intersection, and difference. Right now I am focusing on an intersection method and I am trying to implement the retainAll() method.

I will not include all my code but just the methods and data fields that relate to what I am trying to accomplish.

my issues lies with trying to find the intersection. for some reason when I run a test, I get an empty list. I only get empty brackets on the output screen. I can't figure out why this happening but I feel it has something to do with the constructors or how I set up the retainAll method. NOTE: this only happens for the intersection method, the union method works perfectly

Thanks for any input, I greatly appreciate it

```
public class Set<T> {

//data fields
private LinkedList<T> L = new LinkedList<T>();
private int size;

//constructor Set with argument used in intersection method
public Set(Set<T> b) {

}


public void add(T item){
    L.add(item);
    size ++;
}

// will remove first instance of specified item
public void remove(T item){
    L.remove(item);
    size--;
} 


public void retainAll(Set<T> x){
    L.retainAll(L);
}

public String toString(){
    return L.toString();
}

public Iterator<T> iterator(){
    return L.iterator();
}



  public static <T> HashSet<T> union(Set<T> a, Set<T>b){
    //create new set c, which will be the combination of A and B
    HashSet<T> c = new HashSet<T>();
    Iterator<T> iter1 = a.iterator();
    Iterator<T> iter2 = b.iterator();

    //go through set A, add to new union
    while(iter1.hasNext()){
        c.add(iter1.next());
    }

    //go through set B, add to new union
    while(iter2.hasNext()){
        c.add(iter2.next());
    }

    return c;






 public static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> a, Set<T>b){
    //create new set intersection, which will contain common items of set A and B
    Set<T> c = new Set<T>(a);   
    c.retainAll(b);
    return c;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<T> c = new Set<T>();    
c.retainAll(b);
return c;
```

`c` never has any of the elements of `a` to start with.  You never mentioned `a` anywhere in that block of code, in fact.  Perhaps you meant

```
Set<T> c = new Set<T>(a);
```

Comment: sorry, just edited it. "a" was originally a parameter but i accidentally left it out when asking my question. regardless. even when "a" is a parameter, it still doesnt work

Comment: Then I suspect the issue may be that your constructor `Set(Set<T> b)` might be incorrect.  Please provide that code.

Comment: I actually have no code inside the constructor. I just set it up so that Set<T> c = new Set<T>() could accept a set as a parameter without getting an error. Do you recommend adding some code to the constructor. I was not sure what do to.

Comment: Presumably, the constructor should add all the elements from its argument.  Otherwise, your `retainAll` method is taking an empty set, retaining nothing from it, and returning the still-empty set.

Answer (score 0):

//constructor Set with argument used in intersection method

```
public Set(Set<T> b) {

}
```

In the above constructor you need to write the code for copying the elements of one set into other because your constructor is doing nothing. it is simply taking the set argument.

```
public static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> a, Set<T>b){
    //create new set intersection, which will contain common items of set A and B
    Set<T> c = new Set<T>(a);   
    c.retainAll(b);
    return c;
```

In the above method, when it is not copying the elements of "a" to "c" the retainsAll method will return empty only.

PS: Please do something with the constructor.